# How to set the force touch titles dynamically

Tags: ios, dynamic, touch, title

I added force touch to my app, and that works great :). But I would like the titles to change to whatever appointment is coming up first. To set the date as a subtitle.

I see that Dropbox can do it, so can anyone tell me how it is done?

[image]
[image]

Add it into your info.plist
[image]

```
UIApplicationShortcutItems
-- Item 0
    -- UIApplicationShortcutItemIconType = UIApplicationShortcutIconTypePlay
    -- UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle    = Present 
    -- UIApplicationShortcutItemUserInfo
        -- key1                           = 1
-- Item 1
°°°
```

and in your delegate file use this code:
where xxxxxx is your PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded))completionHandler 
{
    int updateAttendance = 0;

    if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"xxxxxx.setPresent"])
    {
        updateAttendance = 1;
    }
    if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"xxxxxx.setAbsent"])
    {
        updateAttendance = 3;
    }
    if ([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"xxxxxx.clearAllNotifications"])
    {
        [[beDbAccess sharedInstance] clearAllNotifications];
    }
    if (updateAttendance > 0)
    {
        [[beDbAccess sharedInstance] updateAttendanceNextPlan:updateAttendance];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so as described [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-uiapplicationshortcutitem-quick-action-for-3d-touch), by adding your UIApplicationShortcutIcon programmatically within your application's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let icon = UIApplicationShortcutIcon(type: .add)
    let item = UIApplicationShortcutItem(type: "com.yoursite.yourapp.adduser", localizedTitle: "Add User", localizedSubtitle: "Meet someone new", icon: icon, userInfo: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.shortcutItems = [item]

    if let shortcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.shortcutItem] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {
        if shortcutItem.type == "com.yoursite.yourapp.adduser" {
            // shortcut was triggered!
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: I will test this when I get home. Any idea how it would look like in old style C sharp?

Comment: Yes but only for a few is version. No longer works in cutrznt iOs